# Return the portion of a string before the first occurrence of a character in PHP

Tags: php, string

In PHP, what is the simplest way to return the portion of a string before the first occurrence of a specific character?

For example, if I have a string...

"The quick brown foxed jumped over the etc etc."

...and I am filtering for a space character (" "), the function would return
*"The"*.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->beforeFirst(' ')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L389) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You **could** do this:

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
$substring = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ' '));
```

But I like this **better**:

```
list($firstWord) = explode(' ', $string);
```

Comment: Would that not throw errors? I thought link had to have a matching vairable set (or empty comma delimited) for the number of variables in the array you're exploding?

Comment: in case you want to return the variable instead of assigning it

`return array_shift(explode(' ', $string));`

Comment: If the string(here a space) isn't found the first returns an empty string.  The second returns the whole string.

Comment: You can also use the `limit` parameter in [`explode(…)`](http://php.net/explode), so that `$string` isn't scanned any more than needed: `list($firstWord) = explode(' ', $string, 2);`

Answer (score 114):

For googlers: [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) is better for that:

```
echo strtok("The quick brown fox", ' ');
```

Comment: Only downer about strtok, is if the token isn't found, it returns the whole string.

Comment: Unless what you want is the entire string. Which is exactly what I needed. Thanks for making it explicit.

Comment: Exactly what I needed (including the entire string thing). No need for any error handling as well. Thanks!

Comment: If your string starts with the 'token', it will be skipped; it won't return the empty string before the first 'token'; it will return the first nonempty part between 'tokens'.  It will also return `false` (not an empty string) if you pass an empty string.  A few gotchas.

Answer (score 31):

> [**`strstr()`**](http://php.net/manual/function.strstr.php) Find the first occurrence of a string. Returns part of haystack string starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end of haystack.
>
> Third param: If TRUE, strstr() returns the part of the haystack before the first occurrence of the needle (excluding the needle).

```
$haystack  = 'The quick brown foxed jumped over the etc etc.';
$needle    = ' ';
echo strstr($haystack, $needle, true);
```

Prints `The`.

Comment: I tried this code and got a warning: "Wrong parameter count for strstr()". The reason is that this code only works as of PHP 5.3.0. I'm using an earlier version of PHP.

Comment: If the needle isn't found it returns false.  Which is what you'd expect.  So personally this  feels like the better answer.  In many of the other answers you'd probably also need to check the string contains the token otherwise you get unpredictable results.  Unless of course it's a given.

Comment: Clean, and simple with good naming conventions for a clear understanding.

Comment: This Answer should have more upvote since I use `strstr` to cut large text int half and `strstr` works bothways up and down :) ;

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the etc etc.";

$splitter = " ";

$pieces = explode($splitter, $string);

echo $pieces[0];
```

Comment: If the splitter isn't found it returns the whole string.

Comment: @Soaku, it's just an observation.

Comment: `explode()` should be limited.  This answer should be explained -- not just to be educational but so that search engines have something to chew on.

Answer (score 4):

To sum up, there're four ways. Delimiter `=`:

```
substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '='));
explode('=', $str)[0];
strstr($str, '=', true);
strtok($str, '=');
```

This table illustrates output differences. Other outputs are pretty isomorphic.

```
+---------+----------------+----------+-------+----------------+-------+-------+
| $str    | "before=after" | "=after" | "="   | "no delimeter" | 1     | ""    |
+---------+----------------+----------+-------+----------------+-------+-------+
| substr  | "before"       | ""       | ""    | ""             | ""    | ""    |
| explode | "before"       | ""       | ""    | "no delimeter" | "1"   | ""    |
| strstr  | "before"       | ""       | ""    | false          | false | false |
| strtok  | "before"       | "after"  | false | "no delimeter" | "1"   | false |
+---------+----------------+----------+-------+----------------+-------+-------+
```

If troubles with multibyte appear then try for example `mb_strstr`:

```
mb_strstr($str, 'ζ', true);
```

Further notice: `explode` seems to be more straightforward, deals with multibyte and by passing third parameter returns both before and after  delimeter

```
explode('ζ', $str, 2);
```

Comment: The falsey ternary check is not always reliable if the substring before the needle is falsey.  Gotcha: https://3v4l.org/AQXhc  Also, `strpos($str, ' ')` might return `false` or offset `0`. That line of code is not reliable either.

Comment: That seems like a real opportunity, then, for you to improve your answer with an [edit].  Please always be generous, reliable, and accurate when you share insights with researchers.

Comment: hopefully improved now

Answer (score 1):

The **strtok()** function splits a string into smaller strings,
for example:

```
$string = "The quick brown";
$token = strtok($string, " "); // Output: The
```

And if you don’t have spaces: print all characters

```
$string = "Thequickbrown";
$token = strtok($string, " "); // Output: Thequickbrown
```